# flutter: Another exception was thrown: No MaterialLocalizations found

Tags: flutter, android-alertdialog

I am trying to show an Alert Dialog on press of a button in Flutter.
Following is my code

```
main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Different Widgets",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: showAlertDialog()
      );
  }

  void _dialogResult(String value) {
    if (value == "YES") {
      print("YES");
    } else {
      print("NO");
    }
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  Widget showAlertDialog() {
    TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Different Widgets"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: textEditingController,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print("Hi");
                  AlertDialog dialog = AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("Hi"),
                    content: Text(
                      textEditingController.text,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _dialogResult("YES");
                          },
                          child: Text("YES")),
                      FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _dialogResult("NO");
                          },
                          child: Text("NO")),
                    ],
                  );

                  showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => dialog);
                },
                child: Text("Click Me"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

What does this has to do with Localisation, I cannot follow. I did the same steps as per the docs. I am able to see the button but on click of that button I keep getting error. I tried writing print statement inside of button click and the print statement appears in the log, definitely something wrong with AlertDialog.

Comment: Can you show us your MaterialApp ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet I have added the entire code. Please check the edited question

Comment: Try to extract `showAlertDialog` into a widget instead of a function

Comment: @RémiRousselet Tried doing that but does not work

Answer (score 1):

You may get `No MaterialLocalizations found` error while showing dialog using [`showDialog()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) class in Flutter. The issue is putting child widget on `home` property of [`MaterialApp()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) widget without creating new widget class.

One way to solve is putting [`MaterialApp()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) inside `runApp()` and create new class for `home` property.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
      title: "Different Widgets",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ),
  );
}

/*
place MaterialApp() widget on runApp() and create
new class for its 'home' property
to escape 'No MaterialLocalizations found' error
*/

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return showAlertDialog();
  }

  void _dialogResult(String value) {
    if (value == "YES") {
      print("YES");
    } else {
      print("NO");
    }
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  Widget showAlertDialog() {
    TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Different Widgets"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: textEditingController,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print("Hi");
                  AlertDialog dialog = AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("Hi"),
                    content: Text(
                      textEditingController.text,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _dialogResult("YES");
                          },
                          child: Text("YES")),
                      FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _dialogResult("NO");
                          },
                          child: Text("NO")),
                    ],
                  );

                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => dialog);
                },
                child: Text("Click Me"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]